# Anime set in the future where naturally born and artifically created humans coexist

Tags: toward-the-terra

Some years back, I've seen this anime at a friend's place ...

I was about a city in the future where "pure" (naturally born) humans were only a few and the rest were created artificially, I don't remember if this was the case about the entire world or just located in one geographical point.

What I do remember is that the city was ruled by a council of old men (naturally born humans), that one day decided to give the artificially created humans the ability to procreate and thus to actually kill the entire remaining naturally born humans.

Probably it was about the entire world...

And I think I'm getting a bit confused here but, I think in this anime there was in the 1st episode a car that wasn't using wheels like any other, but was hovering instead.

And this anime didn't have the gloomy feeling like ergo proxy... it was rather busy and filled with life (the city at least)...

It could be that the water level had risen but I'm not sure...

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of how long ago "some years back" is?

Comment: I have a feeling you're thinking about one of the versions of [Appleseed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appleseed_(film)), probably the 2004 film.

Comment: i know appleseed and it's surelly not like that, it doesn't have a gloomy or noir-like atmosphere ... and about the time ... I think it was from before 2010 ... or i could be mistaken ... i just thought someone could remember a theme like that ...

Comment: No thats definitely the appleseed movie. @clockwork-muse I suggest you post an answer with referemces to the described situations

Comment: dude, really now, i looked at apleseed again, and it's not it ...main character is a boy/man . and there are not androids or cyborgs ... there are some explosions and some death but it is definitely NOT apleseed.  thx for the reply.

Comment: also there are no gods of any kind, nor superpowers

Comment: yea... um your initial description includes nothing anywhere near gods or superpowers.  As of the question text this matches appleseed like the lid on the pot. If you have more information to add to the question, you should do so.

Comment: from i squeeze out of my brain, there are some conflicts because of some murders against naturals, and the chief of police or security force is an artificial midle age tough  woman, who get's her hand on the micro chip that contains the protocols that allows the artificials to procreate and yet she still holds it safe, locked away, until the case of murders is solved ... and in the end all those murders are related to the council of those old natural. even the artificials reject the idea of killing all the naturals. even if the artificial where crated in a way  that they will never start wars.

Comment: @Andrei that perfectly matches with the appleseed plot as I still know. The murders were only the hook for the story though. Later in the movie they become completely irrelevant

Comment: i understand the feeling, but as i said earlier, there are no mecha-humanoids .. they have completely normal bodies .. except that they cant make babies ... and that is missing part of their programming .. i know it sounds awkward but that's the beauty of it, and i also mentioned the general atmosphere is extra violent, or "film-noir" like theme ...

Comment: my bad, the forgot to add NOT after "atmosphere is"

Comment: Texhnolyze is much too dark and gloomy ... I understand it's confusing my question but I don't think it warrants for insults ...

Answer (score 3):

[Toward the Terra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toward_the_Terra) 2007 remake: *"Under the rule of Superior Dominance all humans are born in vitro and given to carefully selected parents"*.

Answer (score 0):

[Armitage III: Dual-Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armitage_III) maybe?

Doesn't quite match everything you said as it is a bit backwards from what you described.

It is about an artificial human who holds the secret to how the artificial humans can procreate and the people in charge are chasing her to get a hold of it.

Comment: no it's not armitage. armitage is way to old ...

Comment: ok i'll go again: the story starts with a young natural (human) man being received my an artificially created young woman. she has in her possession a prototype hoovering car without wheels. the artificially created humans can not procreate because they were not programmed with the procreation program (king of weird thing), but the council of naturals (some really old and bitter men) decided to wipe out the entire naturals population (while giving the artificials the procreation programme)

Comment: this young natural man fight along side the artificials against the decision of that council, and the idea was when the programe was installed and widely distributed the artificials, then the naturals would get wiped out, i think, due to an air born virus ... and the chief or police, or security or whatever law enforcement decides to postpone the launch of the programe in order to do it in a safe manner for everyone. i;m forgeting smth here, it just sliped my mind .. damn it !! thx for the reply.

Comment: Can you remember any character or location names?

Comment: if I could've remember any of it, I assure you, I wouldn't bother anyone with this request.